# Elasticsearch python client: Getting the ES version through API call

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to get the current Elasticsearch version through the python API.
I could easily get it through a http call like

```
import requests
requests.get(http://endpoint:9200)
```

But I am wondering is there any way to get the version through the API call instead of http request to the endpoint. Like

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
```

I went through the Elasticsearch python client documentation, but couldn't find the call that would fetch the current ES version (https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [info](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.info) command:

Example:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
es.info()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get **only** `version number`, you can do something like this:

```
#/usr/bin/env python
import json
import logging
def get_cluster_version(server, user, password):
    cluster_version = "version"

    r = do_request(verb='get',
               server='http://{0}'.format(server),
               auth=(user, password),
               verify=False)
    json_data = json.loads(r.content.decode('utf8'))
    version_number = str(json_data["version"]["number"])
    logging.info("Elastic cluster version " + str(version_number))
```